# RTMP guide to stream something like Skype Video Call

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, stream, rtmp

So everything is setup for my client on my local server but I now have to put it online. I have a couple of questions.
So basically I want to make it somehow like a skype video call. The user receives an appointment at a specific hour to talk to the site administrator. At that given hour, the user logs in and goes to a page to go live with the administrator. Both the administartor need to see and hear the client, and the client the administrator. The questions are :
1. is rtmp even the best sollution for this ? or is this possible with rtmp ?
2. I know how to connect to stream from localhost and then connect to the stream like so
stream

```
ns.connect("rtmp://localhost/streamfolder");
ns.publish("stream", "live");
```

connect

```
ns.connect("rtmp://localhost/streamfolder");
ns.play();
```

is it as simple when you stream from a online server ?
3. I acknowledged that I need a dedicated server to stream, but when I browse hosts I can’t find much info on this. Would this Economy pack do ? http://www.godaddy.com/hosting/virtual-dedicated-servers.aspx?ci=9013 I really like goDaddy so it would be cool if I would stick to them .. Is it hard to install Red5 on a GoDaddy server ?
or should I go with something like this – http://www.videowhisper.com/?p=RTMP+Hosting ?
Thanks!

Comment: to subscribe you should do `ns.play("stream");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1a) The best is RTMFP P2P or via FMS. It's UDP based and uses less bandwidth. To use it you need FMS3.5 or higher or with Adobe Stratus/Cirrus.

1b) Yes it is possible with all 'media' protocols (RTMFP, RTMP and it's tunneled/secured variants)

2) yes, it's that simple when using remote server, you just put your server address instead of localhost

3) In the beginning I would definitely use some media server hosting like wowza or FMS (my favorite is **[INFLUXIS](http://influxis.com/)**, they got great support, they are keen to help with AS3 code also)